# jQuery - how to use multiple selectors one object and one id string

Tags: jquery

I need to serialize two `form` elements into one. But the problem is one has id `#form1` but other is coming from elsewhere as an object let say variable `objform`

Serializing with two string IDs is easy

```
$("#form1, #form2").serialize();
```

How can I serialize one string and one object? Is there an elegant way doing it with object without assigning a dummy random id to the object form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add element to collection:

```
$("#form1").add(myObjectRef).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like so:

```
//object2 into object1
$.extend(object1, object2);
```